# Hive policy in ranger is not working

Tags: hive, apache-ranger

I am using a Kerberos certified cluster. Ranger version is 0.7 and Hive version is 1.2.

After ranger configured Hive policy, it is not working, but hbase and hdfs works fine. I am using Beeline to connect to Hiveserver2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### After careful examination found that parameter configuration error.

---

1. Enable Authorization changed to true
   [image: Authorization]
2. hive.security.authorization.manager changed to ：

   org.apache.ranger.authorization.hive.authorizer.RangerHiveAuthorizerFactory

   This parameter was ：

   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdConfOnlyAuthorizerFactory

[image: Security Settings]